# The application does not start, but it compiles correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making a compass on a smartphone, using a lesson from YouTube.

The application does not open for me, I get an error in the application console.

I just started learning Android Studio and Java, so I am ready to send all the comments from you.

Here's the code itself:

```
package stgamobil.com.compas;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    private ImageView ivDinamic;
    private TextView tvDegree;
    private float current_degree = 0f;
    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    Sensor accelerometer;
    Sensor magnetometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnetometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
        ivDinamic = findViewById(R.id.iveDinamic);
        tvDegree = findViewById(R.id.tvDegree);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        float degree = Math.round(0);



        SensorEvent event = null;
        float[] mGravity= null;
        float[] mGeomagnetic = null;
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            mGravity = event.values;


        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
            mGeomagnetic = event.values;

        if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
            float R[] = new float[9];
            float I[] = new float[9];

            boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
            if (success) {
                float orientation[] = new float[3];

                SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
                degree = orientation[0];
                Float.toString(degree);
                tvDegree.setText("Degrees from north: " + (degree));
            }
        }
        RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(current_degree, -degree, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

        ra.setDuration(210);

        ra.setFillAfter(true);

        ivDinamic.startAnimation(ra);
        current_degree = -degree;

    }


}
```

Better follow the link, you can see better there
Here is my application console

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2BLE.jpg)

---

```
09/30 22:02:42: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3 API 28.
Install successfully finished in 2 s 564 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "stgamobil.com.compas/stgamobil.com.compas.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 5209 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/obil.com.compa: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
W/obil.com.compa: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/WindowInsets;->CONSUMED:Landroid/view/WindowInsets; (light greylist, reflection)
W/obil.com.compa: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getAccessibilityDelegate()Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, linking)
W/obil.com.compa: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
W/obil.com.compa: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
E/SensorManager: Exception dispatching input event.

D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: stgamobil.com.compas, PID: 5209
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.hardware.Sensor android.hardware.SensorEvent.sensor' on a null object reference

at stgamobil.com.compas.MainActivity.onSensorChanged(MainActivity.java:62)
at
android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:833)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)

at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5209 SIG: 9
```

Comment: "Attempt to read from field 'android.hardware.Sensor android.hardware.SensorEvent.sensor' on a null object reference"

Answer (score 3):

If you focus on your code, you'll find that you're creating event variable with null value in `onSensorChanged` method

```
    SensorEvent event = null;
```

and in next lines, you are using it in if condition as

```
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        mGravity = event.values;
```

but you actually need to use `sensorEvent` which is function parameter, you are receiving in

```
 @Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent){..}
```